# ItemDecoration added to ViewPager2 items adds unwanted whitespace at bottom of item layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2, item-decoration

I am displaying a carousel within a RecyclerView. I implemented this carousel using ViewPager2. So the requirement is that the carousel should have no padding/margins and thus extend all the way to edge of the screen. However when displaying the first or last item, there should be a bit of whitespace to the left or right respectively. I've achieved that requirement using `ItemDecoration` applied to the ViewPager2:

```
class CustomItemDecoration(
    private val leftMargin: Int,
    private val rightMargin: Int,
    private val firstLastMargin: Int,
) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect, view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        with(outRect) {
            right = rightMargin
            left = leftMargin
            if (position == 0) {
                left += firstLastMargin
            } else if (position == state.itemCount - 1) {
                right += firstLastMargin
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this has caused the first and last item layouts suddenly having extra whitespace at the bottom. I do not understand why this is the case. Please see the following picture of the first item and the second item, note the whitespace present in the first item that is encircled:

[image]

My item layout looks like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753823/recyclerview-s-itemdecoration-breaks-items-layout-built-with-constraintlayout) and while it's similar, I do not understand how the accepted answer fixes the issue? How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**just use android:scaleType in AppCompatImageView**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**to**

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_screen"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


       //other wise android:scaleType="center"
```